# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED when adding device admin privileges to my app

Tags: android

Adding below lines to my AndroidManifest.xml gives INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error:-

```
<receiver android:name="com.gp.app.antitheft.notifications.AdminManagerActivity"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In addition to this following data is obtained from LogCat :-

04-13 20:24:59.243: W/ActivityManager(594): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/AntiTheft.apk

04-13 20:24:59.253: D/Finsky(1820): [137] PackageVerificationService.getPackageInfo: Cannot read archive for file:///data/local/tmp/AntiTheft.apk in request id=3

04-13 20:24:59.253: D/Finsky(1820): [1] PackageVerificationReceiver.onReceive: Verification requested, id = 3

04-13 20:24:59.253: W/PackageParser(1820): /data/local/tmp/AntiTheft.apk (at Binary XML file line #67):  requires an android:value or android:resource attribute.

As i am very much new to device administration api, i am unable to detect what actually problem is. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing else, you need a `<meta-data>` element, pointing to an XML resource where you describe what device administration capabilities you wish to use:

```
<receiver
  android:name="AdminReceiver"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.app.device_admin"
    android:resource="@xml/device_admin"/>

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Where `res/xml/device_admin.xml` in [my sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/DeviceAdmin/LockMeNow) contains:

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock/>
    </uses-policies>

</device-admin>
```

because this sample project will lock the device upon demand.

You can read more about device administration in [the Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) and in [Android development books written by balding authors](http://commonsware.com/Android). :-)

Comment: Now that the initial problem is fixed I am getting following error in LogCat:-                                                                                                                                                     04-14 18:56:05.750: E/InstalledAppDetails(29833): Exception when retrieving package:com.gp.app.antitheft.startup
04-14 18:56:05.750: E/InstalledAppDetails(29833): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.gp.app.antitheft.startup                                                          although startup package is defined in my app.

Comment: @user3279837: I would recommend that you ask another StackOverflow question, where you provide the full stack trace plus the relevant section from your manifest. With just what you have here in this comment, I cannot help you.